# Excel formula to find two words after the prefix

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I'm exporting a Jira issue into Excel to pull data from the description.

An example of the format would be:
"Author: Bob Bryant   This is a test JIRA"

So that entire string occupies a single cell in Excel

I need to do an `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Author*",Description)),"Author:","")`

But instead of '"Author:"' I need it to take the 2 words after that (users full name), in this case I need it to take "Bob Bryant"

Comment: What happens if a name has initials or a middle name?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Excel is not able to use regular expression (which would be much easier). You can workaround it with a temporary text substitution using `SUBSTITUTE` function.

With:

- `Prefix` - the cell with the prefix, e.g. "Author:"
- `Description` - the cell with original/source text

This is the formula you need is:

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH(Prefix;Description));"(no "&Prefix&" found)";IFERROR(TRIM(MID(Description;LEN(Prefix)+1;SEARCH("$$$";SUBSTITUTE(Description&" ";" ";"$$$";3))-LEN(Prefix)));"(too short)"))
```

Let's explain deeper:

```
=IF(                                     
    ISERR(SEARCH(Prefix;Description));    -- consider only cells with the right prefix (Author:)
    "(no "&Prefix&" found)";              -- Prefix not found: return message
    IFERROR(                              -- Prefix found: proceed
        TRIM(                             -- remove any leading/trailing spaces
            MID(                          -- return the text between prefix and 3rd space
                Description;
                LEN(Prefix)+1;            -- start after the prefix
                SEARCH(                   -- end before the substituted text ($$$)
                    "$$$";
                    SUBSTITUTE(           -- substitute 3rd space (most important!)
                        Description&" ";  -- add extra space (in case there's no other text after the name)
                        " ";
                        "$$$";
                        3))-LEN(Prefix)));"(too short)"))
```

Note, you might need to replace `;` with `,` in your formula (depending on your system locales/regional settings).

Comment: Please note this will work only for 2-word names and only if Author: starts in the cell. Otherwise you would have to change the formula accordingly.